# Popup shown to authors attempting to delete answered questions is incorrectly shown to other delete voters, if there are no pending delete votes

Tags: bug, vote-to-delete, popups

When voting to delete [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967262) I got the following popup message:

[image]

This appears to be the popup user's get when trying to delete their *own* answered question. I'm not the author of this question, so this popup shouldn't be shown to me.

I'm aware of at least one other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968807) where this has happened, as [reported by Vega in SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53262602), though other users have claimed to see this incorrect popup as well, on other questions.

Not all users see the popup on the question when trying to delete it. The user who saw the message keeps seeing it, at least until one other user has cast a delete vote, after which it's no longer shown. In both instances, the message was shown to the user who tried to cast the first delete vote.

Comment: (should be migrated, not deleted)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I have no objections to it being migrated to a site where it's on-topic, for example Software Recommendations might be appropriate. However, questions older than 60 days can't be migrated, so that's not an option here.

Comment: That should be fixed instead of deleting user content and creating 404s.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Sure, that's a reasonable POV. However, whether this question (or questions in general) *should* be deleted, or not, isn't really relevant here.

Comment: Are you still able to reproduce?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog The 2 linked questions here are already deleted, so I can't test those specifically. I tried it on a couple of other questions matching similar criteria, and was unable to reproduce. From what I recall, this was a fairly rare occurrence, so there may be a fairly strict set of conditions required for this to appear.